# Need help identifying sillcock valve make / model

Tags: plumbing

Need help identifying the sillcock valve shown in photograph.

[image: Sillcock Valve]

Comment: Actually is leaking inside the wall.

Answer (score 1):

That faucet has a few years on it. If it is leaking inside the wall you probably should just replace the faucet. It doesn't have to be the same brand.
Shut off the water and determine the source of the leak. In snow country it could be a burst pipe due to freezing. You'll have to access it from inside the house. If the inside of the wall is unfinished great, otherwise you'll have to open the wall. It will need to dry out anyway.
If you're in cold weather country you may want to replace it with a freezeless faucet.

Comment: Thanks. The galvanized pipe is between the brick and a wire mess stucco wall. There is also a drywall behind the stucco supported on 3"x4" studs. Do you think it can be unscrewed from the outside?

Comment: You posted this as an answer which isn't permitted on this site. You should delete it and repost it as a comment. If the supply line is galvanized pipe you should be able to unscrew the faucet from the outside. If the leak is from the threaded connection you might be able to clean it up, apply sealant and reuse the same faucet. But the leak may be in the supply line in the wall. Again - you should do the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to respond on this site. That way we can better help you.

Comment: In unscrewing the faucet be aware it may unscrew at another fitting from inside the wall such as at an elbow. That's okay if it does - your first objective is to find the source of the leak. Depending on where it is you may have to open the wall anyway.